# Find a String in a huge text file

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am developing an internal App that will search things in one text file (~60,000 lines).
The user will type a String in the UISearchBar on his iPhone and the App will return the line(s) where the String is located.

This is how I do it.

First I split my text file into an array called **entriesInLine**:

```
    var entriesInLine: [String] = []

    let fileWithEntries = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("database", ofType: "txt")
    var entriesFromFile = String(contentsOfFile: fileWithEntries!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    if let content = entriesFromFile {
        self.entriesInLine = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        println(self.entriesInLine.count)
    }
```

Then I want the user to be able to search the database using the UISearchBar. Here is my Search method:

```
 func filterEntries(searchText: String) {
    for var i = 0; i < self.entriesInLine.count; i++  {
        if ( self.entriesInLine[i].rangeOfString(searchText) != nil) {
            self.filteredEntries.append(extractEntry(entriesInLine[i]))                            

        }
```

And here is my **searchDisplayController** method:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterEntries(searchString)
```

}

Everything is kind of working but it's too slow because arrays are huge.

Do you know a faster way of searching the content in my text file?

I will really appreciate your help for that!

Thank you

Comment: try to change your logic for searching and storing in array.storing in array is taking much time, than finding string.

Comment: Thank you. So now I am using self.entriesFromFile!.rangeOfString(searchText) to read the file directly as a String. It's way faster to search for things now but I can't get the Line number to extract it. How could I do, maybe use a Scanner?

Comment: what range of string is returning location of string or number of count of that string?

Comment: I can get the range of the found string but not the number of the current line

Comment: in range you are getting location from where string is started? with range.location

Comment: rangeOfString return a range location from the beginning of the string.

Comment: ok wait m working on it will reply you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this I have Tested.

```
 var bundle: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("File", ofType: "")!
 var entriesFromFile: NSString = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(bundle, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &attributeError) as NSString
 var range: NSRange = entriesFromFile.rangeOfString("rrr")
 var substring: NSString = entriesFromFile.substringToIndex(range.location)
 var arr: NSArray = substring.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

 print("Occurence of String in File on Line Number", arr.count)
```

Comment: That's great. Many thank for your work. I had to use   entriesFromFile = NSString(contentsOfFile: bundle, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)! as NSString because in my Xcode stringWithContentsOfFile is deprecated. It's working well!! But I get this error sometimes: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 9223372036854775807 out of bounds; string length 7098003'                                              I guess the index became huge. This happen in my UISearchBar when I change my search text.

Comment: Instead of using the substring, when you read in the file, build an array of the start of each line (0,location of each \n +1). When you get the offset to the word in the string, just do a binary search for the line in the range with the array. Faster than chopping the string up each time.

Comment: If I test if range.length != 0 before executing the substringToIndex everything is working perfectly